# PHP DateTime: How can i re write code to run on PHP 5.1.6

Tags: php

How can i run this code to **PHP 5.1.6**

```
 $obj['timezone'] = IssetPost('tz');
 $tz = new DateTimeZone($obj['timezone']);
 $date = new DateTime('NOW');
 $date->setTimeZone($tz);
 $currentDate = $date->format('m j Y H i');
 $datePart = explode(" ",$currentDate);
```

I am rewriting it and my code so far is:

```
$obj['timezone'] = IssetPost('tz');
$tz = date_default_timezone_set($obj['timezone']);
$date = date('NOW');
$date = date_default_timezone_get($tz);
$currentDate = $date->format('m j Y H i');
$datePart = explode(" ",$currentDate);
```

I am getting this error

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on a non-object in /var/www/users/sys3/htdocs_ssl/pc/cid/conference_schedule.php on line 27

thank you

Comment: PHP 5.1.6 is 10 years old - that's very, very legacy. are you certain there's no chance to update your system instead?

Comment: my first thought, though, is that `$date = date_default_timezone_get($tz);` is at fault, since it overwrites your `$date = date('NOW');`

Comment: You didn't bother checking [the manual entry of date() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), did you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date()` returns a formatted date string for a given timestamp, which is "now" by default. Just write `$currentDate = date('m j Y H i')`.